# Using &block to pass html to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I pass a block to a method. For example:

```
# in the view
button(link) do
  '<div>html content</div>'
end

def button(&block)
  block
end
```

I have the following code which is working:

```
# in helper file
def button(&block)
  link_to '/' do
      block.call.html_safe
  end
end


# in the view
button {'<div>html content</div>'}
```

Answer (score 3):

So, you just want to pass the block on to link_to? Do this.

```
def button(&block)
  link_to '/', &block
end
```

Comment: `html_safe` is lost :)

Comment: Ah, that is true. In this case, I find the question unclear. :)

Comment: `link_to '/', &-> { block.call.html_safe }`?

Comment: Leaving out `html_safe` is perfectly fine. `button` should not be responsible for marking the string as safe.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely messing things up. What you are trying to achieve is easily achievable without any `yield` magic, with plain old good method parameter:

```
def button html
  link_to '/', html.html_safe
end

button '<div>html content</div>'
```

If one wants to yield a value from a block, do something with it and pass it further, one might:

```
def button
  raise unless block_given?
  λ = Proc.new
  link_to '/', &-> { λ.call.html_safe }
end

button { '<div>html content</div>' }
```

Answer (score 1):

use yield:

```
def new_button(link)
  link_to link do
      yield.html_safe if block_given?
  end
end
```

Comment: I am getting the error `undefined method 'html_safe' for 1:Fixnum`

Comment: yield is the same as `block.call`

Comment: how did you invoke the method?